# mailx not send html email

Tags: linux, bash, mailx

mailx does not send emails in HTML format. The html code is inserted as an attachment to the e-mail and not as a body. I tried to send only one html tag instead of reading an entire document, but it is not recognized as html

My Code is:

```
MAIL_TPL="/layout/header.tpl.html"
cat $MAIL_TPL > $MAIL
SUBJECT "Test E-Mail"

(
echo "Content-Disposition: inline"  | cat - $MAIL > temp && mv temp $MAIL
echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7BIT"  | cat - $MAIL > temp && mv temp $MAIL
echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii"  | cat - $MAIL > temp && mv temp $MAIL
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"  | cat - $MAIL > temp && mv temp $MAIL
echo "Subject: ${SUBJECT}" | cat - $MAIL > temp && mv temp $MAIL
echo "To: dest email" | cat - $MAIL > temp && mv temp $MAIL
echo "FROM: my name" | cat - $MAIL > temp && mv temp $MAIL
echo 
echo "$(cat $MAIL)") | mailx -v -s "$SUBJECT" -S smtp-use-starttls -S smtp-auth=login -S smtp=smtp://smtp.myhost:587 -S from="my email" -S smtp-auth-user=myuser -S smtp-auth-password=mypassword -S ssl-verify=ignore -S nss-config-dir=/etc/pki/nssdb/ emaildest
```